# How to let the scan function accept the empty string in r?

Tags: r

I have a txt file which contains a list of words separated by a newline.  I have in total 5 words separated by newline and the first word is the empty string. When I run the following code it returns "Read 4 items". It has ignored the empty string. I want it to be considered as one of the items. 
Here's my code to read the items from the text file.

```
vector1 <- scan("output1.txt", what="", sep="\n",skip = 0). Thanks
```

Comment: scan has a blank.lines.skip parameter that defaults to TRUE which you should set to FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readLines` for this to work:

I have a text file named `words.txt` as:

```
<empty string>
hi
hello
bye
ciao
```

After I run `readLines`:

```
a <- readLines('words.txt')
> a
[1] ""      "hi"    "hello" "bye"   "ciao"
```

It is capturing the empty string properly.